# Switching between two SQS Queues on a daily schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have the following use case:

I have a `SQS Queue` subscribed to a `SNS topic`. Messages are being sent to the queue continuously. The job is to process the messages in the `SQS Queue` at intervals of a day. By this I mean that I would let the messages come in to the `SQS` for the entire day and then process the messages which have come till (say) midnight. This should be a daily job (i.e I do not want to poll the `SQS Queue` for messages indefinitely).

The problem is that when I am reading the messages from the `SQS Queue`, new messages are continuously entering the queue. Hence, I am not able to stop reading the messages (I stop when the queue is empty).

The solution which I have thought involves switching between the queues and goes like this:

- I would have two `SQS queues`.
- First queue collects the messages from `SNS` for `day 1`.
- On `Day 2`, I would subscribe `SQS Queue-2` to the `SNS` topic and unsubscribe `Queue-1`.
- Would read the messages from `Queue-1`. I would be able to stop since I would not get any new messages.
- Next day I would subscribe `SQS Queue-1`  and unsubscribe `Queue-2`.

Is this approach feasible programmatically? Can this be done in Java? Or does someone has a better solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible to accomplish this programmatically, and with Java. You should have a look at the AWS SDK for Java https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/

Comment: I recommend subscribing a Lambda function to the SNS topic, and have the Lambda function push messages to the appropriate SQS queue based on the date/time. Trying to move the SNS topic subscription around to different queues opens you up to the possibility of lost messages as well as individual messages being delivered to multiple queues.

Comment: Can you provide more information about WHY you wish to do it only once per day? Is this to save money?  What type of processing are you doing -- it might be a good use-case for Lambda, which could also be a cheaper option.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein To start with, whenever some record in DynamoDB is updated, a notification is sent which contains the `hash key` of the record being updated. Subscribing SQS to this SNS, I get the hash key message which I use to query the DDB table to get the entire record and process it further.During the day a record can be updated multiple times.Multiple notifications and hence messages would be received by SQS, all containing the same hash key. So, I let in messages come in till end of day and then filter out the unique messages (ie hash key) and then query DDB to get the persisted data.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a step back, it appears that your requirement is:

- Data is (somehow) updated in DynamoDB
- For each update, you wish to retrieve the updated data and do some processing. This does not have to happen immediately -- daily is acceptable.

One option would be to take advantage of **DynamoDB Streams** and **AWS Lambda**:

- When data is updated in DynamoDB, **DynamoDB Streams** can generate a message containing both the current AND the previous values of that data. (In the case of new items, it only contains the current values. In the case of deleted items, it only contains the previous values prior to deletion.)
- **AWS Lambda** can retrieve the message from DynamoDB Streams and perform an operation on it. Lambda functions can be written in Java, Python or node.js. This function would look at the previous/current values and do whatever processing you desired.

**That's all!** No need for queues, cron jobs nor waiting until the evening to process a batch of messages. If no messages are generated, there is no cost. If lots of messages are generated due to updates in DynamoDB, then Lambda will automatically scale to run a function for each update. (Note, however, that if one value is updated quickly in a short period of time, there is no guarantee that Lambda will run in the same order.)

Comment: Thanks!! Sounds good. But its not for each update that I want to retrieve the data. For instance, a DDB record with hash key say `1` had data `xxx`. Update happened data changed to `yyy`. Another update happened data changed to `zzz`. Now, I wish to process only the `zzz` data. I do not care what intermediate data that record had. Is your solution still applicable?

Comment: The above method will process EVERY change. While you only want the "latest" update, there might not be any harm in processing every update. It is simpler, and using Lambda could actually be cheaper than using SQS+EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the approach you mentioned is possible to implement.

I have a simple alternative to this situation.
1. Create a crontab(in-case it's a Linux system) or scheduled task(for Windows system) to execute a very small program at the end of each day, say at the time-stamp 23:59:59.

2. This so called small program just sends a simple message to your SQS queue in use(the one to which SNS sends messages), say 'SNSqueue', 
   This message is just a separator/marker message and can have body as simple as "newday".

> String SNSqueue = SNSqueue_URL
>       sqs.sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(SNSqueue, "newday"));

3. When you start pulling messages from this SQS queue, run through 'for' loop inside which you can apply message processing logic.
   The loop breaks when you receive the message with body as "newday"

> ```
>  List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
>     for (Message message : messages) 
>     {
>       //message processing logic
>       //Delete the processed messages after processing from this queue to make room for new messages or archive them over disk
>       if(message.getBody().equals("newday"))
>           System.exit(0); //or any relevent termination code
>     }
> ```

This way you can avoid switching between the queues everyday.

Answer (score -1):

your solution works but it's more complicated than it need to be.

Alternative solutions:

1) Look at the timestamps on the messages. Once you see one that is for the "current" day you stop processing. SQS will give you these timestamps, through the SDK

2) As you start processing insert a "marker" message in the queue yourself. When you see the marker, stop processing. Each worker that pulls messages from the queue needs to do this (ie you need more than one marker if you have multiple workers).

Comment: SQS doesn't guarantee order, so there can be problems with both of your suggested solutions.

Comment: @ Mircea this is not how SQS works. Because of the distributed nature of the queue, SQS does not guarantee a FIFO order.

Comment: I believe that given your pattern what I'm describing is more than reasonable. Yes, you may process a few more messages in case of 2), but given that's a day's worth of messages you'll have this issue either way (think clocks not being in perfect sync and/or messages landing in the old queue while the SNS topic is switched to the other queue).

Comment: @Mircea Your solutions also don't allow for multiple threads or servers to be processing messages. That's a serious scalability issue.

Comment: @MarkB look at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_Message.html -> Attributes -> SentTimestamp This can definitely run on multiple machines / threads. LMK if you want me to build you a quick sample that shows how this works. Again: you receive and you look at the SentTimestamp. When you start processing you record the timestamp. When you see messages that have a SentTimestamp higher newer than your start timestamp you stop processing.

Comment: The ordering is not *guaranteed* but in practice and for all practical purposes, the messages are delivered in order.  You can get all bogged down in theory but this is a perfectly sensible strategy. +1

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot especially when you are talking about processing a day's worth of messages :)